# Fingerprint scanner doesn't work

Tags: windows, windows-10, reinstall, scanner, fingerprint

I reinstalled windows 10 pro on my laptop, an Asus VivoBook s430fn with an i7, MX150 2gb 1tb hdd, 8gb ram. When I went in sign-in options I tried to set up a fingerprint but it said that it couldn't find any digital finger print scanner that is compatible with Windows Hello. I also went in device manager but there were no biometrical devices. I tried to download the drivers for it from Asus, did what it said step by step, restarted my laptop but it was still the same.
It would mean a lot if someone could help me.

Comment: Best bet is contact ASUS support directly. They may replace the faulty unit.

Answer (score 0):

If the device (FP scanner) is not in Device Manager, that means it has in all likelihood failed.  Since you have the device driver on hand, you can try adding it, but auto device detect usually works very well.

You should contact ASUS support to get the scanner replaced.